# How to get the display depth of the screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, screen

How do I get the colors of the screen? I'd like to know if the screen is set to True Colors (32 bits) or High Colors (16 bits).

I've been Googling and thought it would be easy to find, but I can't find anything (maybe I have to work on my Google skills?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [`BitsPerPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bitsperpixel.aspx) property:

```
int bitsPerPixel = Screen.PrimaryScreen.BitsPerPixel;
```

Comment: I would have written the same. Additionaly the complete name is System.Windows.Forms.Screen if anyone should wonder

Answer (score 0):

GetDisplayMode function in DirectX9 API can help you,I guess.You will simply write two statements after including necessary headers;

```
D3DDISPLAYMODE currentMode;
pDevice->GetDisplayMode(0,&currentMode);
```

After,you can check depth value like;

```
currentMode->Format
```

I'm sure there are other WinAPI functions,but thats all I know.

EDIT: Did not see you mentioned Winforms. This is useless then